# Javascript Regex capture multiline content from each newline entry

Tags: javascript, regex, multiline, capturing-group

I am doing Javascript Regex to process and transform some raw data to 2D array.

### Task Briefing (JS only):

Transforming raw string data to 2D array.

### Raw Data Input :

Here is a piece of sample with 4 entries, a new entry will go to a newline. Entry 3 comes with multiline content.

> 2012/12/1, AM12:21 - user1‬: entry1_wasehhjdsaj
>
> 2012/12/2, AM9:42 - user2‬: entry2_bahbahbah_dsdeead
>
> 2012/12/2, AM9:44 - user3‬: entry3_Line1_ContdWithFollowingLine_bahbahbah
>
> entry3_Line2_ContdWithABoveLine_bahbahbah_erererw
>
> entry3_Line3_ContdWithABoveLine_bahbahbah_dsff
>
> 2012/12/4, AM11:48 - user7‬: entry4_bahbahbah_fggf

(raw string data, without empty line. )
*Updated: Sorry for misleading, the end of contents do not necessary come with same END pattern, but just a line break.*

*How the pattern actually ends?* (Thanks @Tim Pietzcker's comment).
The content should be end with a line break and following with next entry timestamp start. (You can assume the entry contents do not contain any similar timestamp pattern.)

I understand this may be a trouble regex question, so ANY OTHER JS METHOD ACHIEVING SAME GOAL WILL ALSO BE ACCEPT.

### My current regex with capture group:

```
/^([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})[\/]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[\/]([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1]), ([A|P])M([1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d) - (.*?): (.*)/gm
```

### Desired capture result:

**MATCH 1**

1. `2012`
2. `12`
3. `1`
4. `A`
5. `12`
6. `21`
7. `user1‬`
8. `entry1_wasehhjdsaj`

**MATCH 2**

1. `2012`
2. `12`
3. `2`
4. `A`
5. `9`
6. `42`
7. `user2‬`
8. `entry2_bahbahbah_dsdeead`

**MATCH 3**

1. `2012`
2. `12`
3. `2`
4. `A`
5. `9`
6. `44`
7. `user3‬`
8. `entry3_Line1_ContdWithFollowingLine_bahbahbah entry3_Line2_ContdWithABoveLine_bahbahbah_erererw  entry3_Line3_ContdWithABoveLine_bahbahbah_dsff`

**MATCH 4**

(to be skipped...)

---

## Problem:

There is a problem when I capture Entry 3, I can't capture the 2nd & 3rd line content of Entry 3. If the entry only contains ONE line content, the regex work fine.

**How can I capture Entry 3 with Multi-line content?** I try to work with m modifier, but I have no idea how to deal with Multi-line contents and newline entry at the same time.

**If it is impossible achieve with js regex, please suggest another js approach to transform the raw data to 2D array as ultimate goal.**

THANKS!

[image]
*the end of contents do not necessary come with same END pattern, but just a line break.*

Testing: https://regex101.com/r/eS9pY5/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a single regex that will match the strings you have the way you need:

```
^(\d{4}|\d{2})\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]), ([AP])M([1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d) - (.*?): ((?:(?!(?:\d{4}|\d{2})\/(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))[\s\S])*)(?=\n|$)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jB9jC4/7)

The last capturing group is no longer a greedy dot matching `.*` but a tempered greedy token `(?:(?!([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))[\s\S])*` matching everything up to the end of string or the date pattern.

If we unroll it to make more efficient:

```
^(\d{4}|\d{2})\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]), ([AP])M([1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d) - (.*?): (\D*(?:\d(?!(?:\d{3}|\d)\/(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))\D*)*)(?=\n|$)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/jB9jC4/6)

Answer (score 1):

Multiline doesn't work that way in javascript, but you can workaround it with `[\s\S]`. This class matches every character and \n as well. Note the `*?` instead of `*` after it, to stop it from being greedy and only go until the 1st `END`:

```
^([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})[\/]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[\/]([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1]), ([A|P])M([1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d) - (.*?): ([\s\S]*?END)$
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/mT8rI4/3

Comment: Updated: Sorry for misleading, the end of contents do not necessary come with same END pattern, but just a line break.

Answer (score 1):

Dots (`.`) don't match newline characters. There is a character class that matches everything (`[\S\s]`), but you don't want to use that without precautions - otherwise `[\S\s]*` would match all the entries at once.

So you need to tell the regex engine to stop matching when the next match begins. We can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that, and we'll just feed the timestamp pattern into that:

```
/^([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]), ([AP])M([1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d) - ([^:]*): ((?:(?!^([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]), ([AP])M([1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d))[\S\s])*)/gm
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mT8rI4/4).

Comment: javascript regexes don't have `s` flag

Comment: @jcubic: Yes, that was a copy/paste mishap.

Comment: Updated: Sorry for misleading, the end of contents do not necessary come with same END pattern, but just a line break.

Comment: @cint: If they do, how can you tell when the pattern actually ends?

Comment: good question! the content should be end with a line break and following next entry timestamp start. (You can assume the entry contents do not contain any same timestamp pattern). 

I understand this may be a trouble regex question, so ANY OTHER JS METHOD WILL ALSO BE ACCEPT.